# Indirect function references

Tags: function, methods, reference, dart

Shouldn't this (or something like it) work?  and/or How can I accomplish this some other way?

```
class A {
   void init() {initializeSomething()}
}

main() {
   var f = A.init;
   A a = new A();
   a.f();
}
```

I want, in general, to store a reference to an instance method
somewhere, then call it somewhere else (something I can do in most other
languages, including JavaScript).  I thought functions were first class
in Dart... and aren't methods functions?  Are methods *not* first class?

It works as long as the method is static (which is of no use in my case) but not for instance methods...

Comment: Do I have the right group?  I clicked on the link in the dart pages which said: "ask questions here".  But as you can see I have received no answers...

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  It really seems to reflect badly on the design of dart that this doesn't work naturally, the way one would expect.  Virtually no other similar language that treats functions/methods as first class has this flaw.  Is there a dart implementer out there who can comment on this?  Should I file it as a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Functions and methdods are different. You can only call methods on an instance of a class that has this method.
In your example (`var f = A.init`) you reference an instance method like a static (class) method.

What works is:

make `init` static

```
class A {
   static void init() => initializeSomething();
   // or
   // static void init() {
   //   initializeSomething();
   // }
}

main() {
   var f = A.init;
   A a = new A();
   a.f();
}
```

or use a reference to `init()` of an actual instance of `A`:

```
class A {
   void init() => initializeSomething();
}

main() {
   A a = new A();
   var f = a.init;
   a.f();
}
```

Comment: I am trying to obtain a "reference" to a method, so I can call it later with an actual instance.   init() cannot be static or it would not work with an instance.  The actual instance I need to use does not exist yet.  It will be instantiated later, at which time I will need to call init() through a reference.  Do you understand what I am trying to say?

Comment: I don't know a way without using mirrors (reflection) which is discouraged client side because it is prone to cause code bloat. There might be other ways to achieve something similar but I would need more details about your actual use case to be able to make suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  It really seems to reflect badly on the design of dart that this doesn't work naturally, the way one would expect.  Virtually no other similar language that treats functions/methods as first class has this flaw.  Is there a dart implementer out there who can comment on this?  Should I file it as a bug?

Comment: What language supports this? Maybe I am missing something. I don't know any OO language where this is possible. I think https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?nomobile=true#!forum/core-dev is the right place to start a discussion.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, dylan, haskel, ruby, and c++ (via virtual) support
this.  I bet it is a performance issue since (with this limitation) all
the dispatch information can be computed at compile time, and there is
no need to keep dispatch tables at run time.  If performance is the
issue, a discussion would probably be of little value as the dart
performance trade-offs I have seen so far have been made in favor of
speed.  Do you disagree with me on the languages I mentioned?  If so, I
will do further research...  Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: None of the languages are very similar to Dart. I suggest to just ask and see what the language gurus respond.